# Get user email address with Facebooker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker

I know the user needs to give the application "extended permission" for access to the email address. I went through the Facebooker documentation (I am using it for an iFrame app for whatever it's worth) but can't find any related stuff in the documentation or any sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected: (Thank you Kunal Dua). Facebook can give you access to the user's email.

See Kunal's comment, below, for more info.

Are you thinking of the OpenAuth authentication with Google or others where you can use the extended permissions to ask for access to the account's email address?

See [blog entry](http://open.bekk.no/2009/12/18/gmail-and-google-calendar-with-openid-and-oauth/) for an example of obtaining the email address from Google

Comment: Facebook started sharing the email address earlier this year:

​http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=355

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Roadmap_Email
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Communicating_with_Users_via_Email